# VMWare and Ubuntu? 

Tags: windows, windows-7, vmware

would a vm workstation running a client of Windows XP or Windows 7 run faster in Ubuntu than on a Windows 7 pc?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Sounds to me that you're asking if it's faster to run a Windows XP/Windows 7 VM *and* Ubuntu at the same time? The answer in that case is that it's always better to run an Operating System *by itself* then running two OS' at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *very much* depends on your hardware. It's impossible to answer, you can only try out both.

However: If there is a difference, it won't be massive.